# dynamic database operation in python

Tags: python

I have a table in postgres named "VAS_QI" in which I have the below sample data.

```
IP,IN_SOCKET,OUT_SOCKET,IN_THRES,OUT_THRES,PACKETS

56.33.43.56,1,2,1,1,1

56.33.43.56,1,1,1,1,1
```

Using python I want to define a function which reads variable arguments and also take input of a string expression and give the output accordingly:

`expression_val("IN_SOCKET","OUT_SOCKET","IN_THRES",exp="(IN_SOCKET+OUT_SOCKET)/(IN_THRES)")`

Then that should evaluate to below 2 rows

```
3

2
```

I have used psycopg2 to read postgres and read variable . But stuck at the part where i have to evaluate the expression.

```
def expression_val(*k,exp):
  val = ""
  for i in k:
    val = val + i + ","
  str1 = val[:-1]
  sec = "SELECT {} from VAS_QI ".format(str1)
  conn = psycopg2.connect()
  cur - conn.cursor
  cur.execute(sec)
  rows = cur.fetchall()
```

When I run the code. It only fetches the attributes from the database. But I am not able to evaluate the expression with the attributes as the expression is dynamic. The expression will have to be evaluated for each row and updated under a new column "EXPRESSION_VALUE"

Once i get the attributes from the cur.fetchall(). I have the attribute in a list "rows". So, how can i evaluate the expression

Comment: "But stuck at the part where i have to evaluate the expression." What are you stuck on exactly? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do otherwise? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: p.s. Don't use `.format()` on a string that contains a SQL command. This enables a potential SQL injection attack. Instead, learn how to send bound parameters with the string directly to the database.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the expression in python on the client, or by passing "something" to the server so that the database does the calculation?

Comment: I want to evaluate expression in python on the client and not on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Evaluation in database

If you only want the expression evaluated for each row in the table you could try something like this.

```py
def expression_val(exp):
  sec = f'SELECT {exp} from VAS_QI;'
  conn = psycopg2.connect()
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute(sec)
  rows = cur.fetchall()
  conn.close
  return rows

data = expression_val(exp='(IN_SOCKET+OUT_SOCKET)/(IN_THRES)')

print(data)

""" Example Output
[(2,), (3,)]
"""
```

### Evaluation in Python

If you want to evaluate the expression in Python you could use something like this.

Not sure how practical it is and I'm sure it has limitations, for example the expression must contain the fields you are using in the query.

```py
import psycopg2

def expression_val(*k,exp):
  str1 = ','.join(k)
  sec = "SELECT {} from VAS_QI ".format(str1)
  conn = psycopg2.connect()
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute(sec)
  rows = cur.fetchall()
  conn.close
  
  eval_rows = []
  for row in rows:
    eval_dict = dict(zip(k, row))
    eval_exp = exp
    for ky in eval_dict.keys():
      eval_exp = eval_exp.replace(ky, str(eval_dict[ky]))
    eval_rows.append(eval_exp)
  eval_result = [eval(eval_exp) for eval_exp in eval_rows]
  
  return eval_result

data = expression_val("IN_SOCKET","OUT_SOCKET","IN_THRES",exp="(IN_SOCKET+OUT_SOCKET)/(IN_THRES)")

print(data)

""" Example Output

[2.0, 3.0] 

"""
```

Comment: Would this be vulnerable to a call like: `expression_val(exp="1 from VAS_QI; drop table VAS_QI; --")`?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I run that from python I get the error `no results to fetch` but the table doesn't appear to be dropped but when I execute `SELECT 1 from VAS_QI; drop table VAS_QI; -- from VAS_QI;` in `psql` the table is, of course, dropped.

Comment: @norie : I want to do the computation in python and not by running a query in the database actually.

Comment: @norie : Can the code be changed to evaluate for each row ?. Here you are reading everything into a list and later using eval(). I have close to 80,00,000 records and it will hit my performance. I want to evaluate the expression and probably update a column there itself for each row

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what exactly do you want the function to return?

Comment: The function should calculate the expression for each row and update a new column named "EXPRESSION_VALUE". how can i use the eval() which is used in the "eval_result " to run for each row instead of running on a list

Comment: Don't append `eval_exp` to the list `eval_rows` list, use `eval` on it to get the result for the row and then do whatever you want to with it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to query the columns you require, then use pandas on the client to evaluate the expression. This isn't exactly what you want but it should be easy to modify.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd


def query():
    query = """
        SELECT IN_SOCKET,OUT_SOCKET,IN_THRES from VAS_QI
    """
    with psycopg2.connect() as db:   
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, db)
        return df

df = query()
df["exp"] = (df["IN_SOCKET"] + df["OUT_SOCKET"]) / df["IN_THRES"]
```